# search all the files and directories to create thumbnails in php

Tags: php

I want to search through files and create images from jpg files. There's the code:

```
$dir2 = opendir($direction2);
$dir = opendir($direction);

function create_fcat($direction, $width, $direction2, $dir) {
  while(false !== ($fn = readdir($dir))) {
    $n_dir = $direction.'/'.$fn;
    if (is_dir($n_dir) && $fn != '.' && $fn != '..') {
      if ($handle = opendir($n_dir)) {
        create_fcat($fn, $width, $direction2, $handle);
      }
    } elseif ($fn != '.' && $fn != '..') {
      $ext = strtolower(substr($fn,strlen($fn)-3));
      if ($ext == 'jpg') {
        if ($img = imagecreatefromjpeg( $direction.'/'.$fn )) {
          $width_original = imagesx( $img );
          $height_original = imagesy( $img );
          if ($width_original > $height_original) {
            $new_width = $width;
            $new_height = floor( $height_original * ( $width / $width_original ) );
          } else {
            $new_height = $width;
            $new_width = floor( $width_original * ( $width / $height_original ) );
          }
          $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );
          imagecopyresized( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width_original, $height_original );
          imagejpeg( $tmp_img, $direction2.'/large/'.$fn );
        } else {
          echo '<p>The file cannot be loaded.</p>';
        }
      }
    }
  }
  closedir($dir);
}
```

The problem is: when for example we have these files:

- MAIN

  - image1.jpg
  - FOLDER1

    - image2.jpg
    - FOLDER 1.1

      - image3.jpg

Files image1.jpg and image2.jpg are loaded, but image3.jpg is not - it looks like FOLDER 1.1 is treated as file. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$path = '/your/top/level/dir';

$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
 foreach ($objects as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        echo $fileinfo->getFilename() . "\n";
        $fullpath = $fileinfo->getPathname(); // full path to image for resizing
    }
}
```

This would give you all the files in a directory and all sub-directories, you can then resize each image as you wish. I always use imagmagick for this myself as i think the results are generally better than with GD but obviously GD is more commonly installed.

Answer (score 0):

I would use two separate functions:

1. Function *A* to create a thumbnail from a specific image file.
2. Function *B* to read the entries of a directory and

   - calls function *A* if entry is an image file, or
   - calls function *B* if entry is also a directory.

Then you can test and tweak both functions separately.